# Using rolling window to accurately detect sequence in dataframe with repeating values (same head and same tail)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pattern-matching

I have a multiple pandas dataframe each with a column containing values and another with a corresponding matching time.

i.e., : [z,x,y,n,z,z,x, etc.] [1.234, 2.4467, 2.999, 6.432, 9.6764, etc.]

I want to detect a specific pattern (i.e., z,x,y,n,z) and create a new column with info about whether the value is part of the sequence (called 'seq_bool', with either True or False for each value). Which then looks like this:

```
0    1    seq_bool
z  1.234  True
x  2.4467 True
y  2.999  True
n  6.432  True
z  9.6764 True
x  10.111 False
y  11.344 False
z  12.33  True
x  14.33  True
y  15.66  True
n  19.198 True
z  20.222 True
[...]
```

And then I use this information to compute some stats on the corresponding timepoints, essentially only taking values part of the sequence.

I have this already through the following code, from a solution already found on stackoverflow

```
    def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    c = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
    return c
arr = new_df[0].values
b = np.all(rolling_window(arr, N) == sequence_pattern, axis=1)
c = np.mgrid[0:len(b)][b]

d = [i for x in c for i in range(x, x + N)]
new_df['seq_bool'] = np.in1d(np.arange(len(arr)), d)
```

My problem is **that this doesn't accurately recognize the sequence,** because the sequence starts and end with the same character (i.e., 'z' )

Specifically, if I have the following values in my data [z, x, y, n, z, x, y, n, z], the function recognizes all these values are being part of the sequence (and being all 'True') when in fact they are not. There is only one correct sequence(i.e., [z, x, y, n, z]).

I am somewhat new to python, and I don't know how to go about solving this. Is there a way to specify that, when a sequence has been found, output the necessary variable and then discard it and move forward to the next value in the column? 
**As to not mistakenly take the tail of the previous correct sequence (i.e., z) as the beginning of a new sequence.**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what you already have, prior to using it, you could remove all values in `c` for which the distance to the previous value is less than 5, making sure to remove the relevant values before moving on. That is, if `c = np.array([0, 7, 11, 15])`, we'd remove 11 but keep 15.

Now, you can vectorize parts of this as necessary, but otherwise what you are looking for just boils down to

```
i = 0
while i < len(c)-1:
    if c[i+1] - c[i] < 5:
        c = np.delete(c, i+1)
    else:
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be seeing this as a find-substring-problem. Have a look at this if you like:

```
word = ''.join(df['0'].values)
seq_bool = np.zeros(len(word)).astype(bool)
start = 0
while True:
    idx = word.find('zxynz', start)
    if idx < 0:
        break
    else:
        start = idx + 5
        seq_bool[idx:idx+5] =  True

df['seq_bool'] = seq_bool
```

---

**EDIT:**
assumed there's at least one character which is known to *never* show up in `df['0']`, there's an even shorter way:

Let's say `T` would be ok for the indicator job:

```
word = ''.join(df['0'].values)
new_word = word.replace('zxynz', 'TTTTT')
df['seq_bool'] = np.array(list(new_word))=='T')
```